# Why is npm not working in the terminal? I also checked the latest version of node.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, terminal

PS C:\Users\acer\Desktop\demo> npm -v
PS C:\Users\acer\Desktop\demo> npm run start

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWBWH.png)

Why is npm not working in the terminal? I also checked the latest version of node.js
Here, I ran a file in react.js Run, but it doesn't give me any response. I checked NPM several times, but it didn't help.

Comment: Can't help much, because I don't know anything about Powershell, but as a first step, I would invoke npm by explicitly providing a full path to the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading NodeJS from the website again and run the installer.

It is probably an error when installing NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like no npm had been installed.

Try installing or updating the latest version of npm by the following command and check for the version.

```
npm install -g npm
```

**npm -v** should give the version of npm like **10.2.4**

Comment: If npm where not installed, the OP would have gotten an error message when invoking it.

Comment: Also, if npm isn't installed I doubt it could be used to install itself.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren The installation of node.js itself includes a basic version of npm. This bundled npm is used to set up the environment. In `npm install -g npm`,this bundled npm is used to interpret and execute the command and `-g` flag specifies a global installation, meaning npm will be installed system-wide. Running `npm install -g npm` triggers a process that updates npm to the latest version and globally accessible npm installation. [npmDoc](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm), [guide](https://radixweb.com/blog/installing-npm-and-nodejs-on-windows-and-mac)

Comment: It is not just a "basic version", it includes NPM (though it is also optional in the installer). So either he has NPM or he doesn't. It might be broken somehow (bad permissions, corrupted files) but in that case you most likely still can't use it to reinstall itself.